# FindInfiles pdf quirk

Tags: vb.net

I just realized that FileSystem.FindInFiles reports success even if it finds the containsText within the document properties of a .pdf file. This is annoying because the end-user looks for the string in the document and does not find it (in this case, the string was only present in the Title field of the document properties).

Please let me know if there is a way around this problem.

Alternatively, can anyone recommend a reliable, fast search VB-compatible api/library/method to use on a windows fileshare?

Comment: And what question? You need exlude pdf files from search? If yes - just use overloaded method 'returnValue = FileSystem.FindInFiles(directory, _
 containsText, ignoreCase, searchType, _
 fileWildcards)'

Comment: I do not want to exclude .pdf files from my search. I want to search in them as well; just need a way to exclude searching for the string in the document properties.

Comment: I am using iTextSharp to read .pdf files and it works like a charm!